# AppWidgetProvider(Widget) with Service Android

Tags: android, service, android-appwidget

Why in almost all the tutorials or examples people do that:

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
...
    context.startService(resumeIntent);
super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
}
```

Doesn't it mean that the new service is started every time the update is executed? Is it the best solution? Or is it better to do it with sending broadcasts?
And shouldn't

```
context.startService(resumeIntent);
```

better be done in onEnabled method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the service is started ONLY IF it isn't already running: if it is already running it is sent a new Intent in `onStartCommand` and it can process that appropriately.

As far as whether to use this or to use `onEnabled` the advantage this has is that the service is restarted every single time if it is not running: `onEnabled` will start the service but if the service is killed for any reason you may not get it restarted for you.

Comment: The problem that i had is that all my widgets "initialization" was situated in the onStart method, and since i've been using a lot of timers and threads, then all of the threads were initialized again every time, but just now i have discovered that onCreate method is possible in AppWidgetProvider and that helped me a lot